# Change :id default resource identifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, rails-routing

In `Airport` model I'm using `primary_key` as airport international code, but Rails still use `:id` in request.

I've set in `airport.rb`

```ruby
self.primary_key = 'code'
```

And in `airports_controller.rb`

```ruby
def show
  @airport = Airport.find(params[:code])
end
```

But when I try to get `domain.com/airports/led`, I receive:

> Couldn't find Airport without an ID

In request parameters I have

```
{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"airports", "id"=>"led"}
```

If I change in controller `params[:code]` to `params[:id]` it works, but I don't want to use it in this way, cause I don't have `id` column in DB.

Comment: It is not about model, it is about convention due to which  `params` is forming.

Comment: So, you mean, there is no way to change it?

Comment: You can change it, like @suslov answers below, but it's important to realize that `params[:id]` is a controller construct independent of whichever primary key you have defined for your models.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`:param`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters) option to override  the default resource identifier `:id`, when you are declaring your routes in Rails 4:

```ruby
resources :airports, param: :code
```

This should result in the following  URI Pattern:

```
/airports/:code(.:format)
```

So you can access that segment from your controller with `params[:code]`.